# Laravel Update - Crashes Unless I add RememberToken code to every model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, updates

I just have a question about add the three "RememberToken" public functions (getRememberToken(), setRememberToken(), and getRememberTokenName() ). For some reason if I tried to log in and create a new session my page would crash and I would get the "Class Foo contains 3 abstract methods..." until I had add all three to every model I had. The weird thing is that I was trying to sign in with Sessions class but I would get this error until I added the new RememberToken functions to every class I have. Is this normal? Do I need to add the "remember_token" to every table that I use now? If anyone could explain why this is or how I went wrong that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!
Here is an example of one of my models with the 3 RememberToken functions:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Warranty extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $fillable = array( 'id', 'created_by', 'street_address', 'warranty_serialized');

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'warranties';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the order.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the order.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /*4.26 Update to RememberToken*/
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add it to the all models that

```
implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
```

Because those are basically User tables.

Comment: So if I remove that from my other models I won't have to add that code and the models will still be in accordance with best practices?

Comment: In this case it's not really a best practice, it's something users models need to have, because Laravel will check for that column in the users tables. So any of your models doesn't implement those interfaces, you don't need to add it.